Haskell send data to socket from multiple green threads raises throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry
In haskell, when dispatching messages (sendAll) through Network.Socket.ByteString concurrently to the same socket from multiple "green" threads, my profiling data indicates a substantial portion of processing time is consumed by the "throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry" function (44%, as displayed below). Is this primarily due to context switching, or could there be other factors contributing to this observation?
throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry Network.Socket.Internal       Network\Socket\Internal.hs:(172,1)-(187,16) 44.0 0.0

stack trace
sendAll Network.Socket.ByteString.IO Network\Socket\ByteString\IO.hsc:(96,1)-(103,58) 12626 1 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
 send Network.Socket.ByteString.IO Network\Socket\ByteString\IO.hsc:(80,1)-(81,31) 12628 1 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
  sendBuf Network.Socket.Buffer Network\Socket\Buffer.hsc:(84,1)-(93,72)                     12630 1 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
   socket2FD Network.Socket.Buffer Network\Socket\Buffer.hsc:(71,1)-(74,43) 12631 1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    unsafeFdSocket Network.Socket.Types Network\Socket\Types.hsc:145:1-45                            12632 1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
   throwSocketErrorIfMinus1Retry Network.Socket.Internal Network\Socket\Internal.hs:(189,1)-(190,50) 12633 1 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
    throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry  Network.Socket.Internal              Network\Socket\Internal.hs:(172,1)-(187,16) 12634 1 4.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
     sendBuf.clen Network.Socket.Buffer Network\Socket\Buffer.hsc:91:9-31                            12635 1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0


It looks like this function should only get called when recving on a socket.  Are you also running a green thread under the same process that's receiving these messages?  (If so, have you considered considered using a Chan from Control.Concurrent.  I expect it'll perform much better than sockets.)

The receiving end is in a different process in a separate "green" task loop. These two processes could be on different computers. I get your suggestion to use channels, but the use case is really to communicate over the network. Do you mean with "this function" throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry? The stack trace indicates the load is from the sendAll call (check edited post)

Got it.  I was looking at a more recent version of network which threw me off

FWIW I never would have dreamed up this plan. Seems like a recipe for getting parts of different messages interleaved. I'd strongly recommend having just one thread in charge of writing; if you want multiple threads to be able to send messages, have them all coordinate with the designated writer using Chan or MVar or similar.

Thank you for providing the final answer to my question, you're absolutely right.
In my code, the MVar protects the Socket from concurrent writes by multiple threads. I think this is bad practice by design. After switching to Chan with a dedicated loop thread reading from Chan and sending to the Socket, the total runtime percentage of throwSocketErrorIfMinus1ButRetry dropped drastically to 0.

@NickvanGils I'm glad you found a fix! For posterity, I've written that up as an actual answer. And in the future, don't be shy about answering your own question once you find a solution -- that's not considered rude here by any means!

Sharing a socket between threads is pretty unusual. A more common architecture is to have one thread dedicated to writing to the socket, and to coordinate with other threads using MVar or Chan. Like this:
main = do
    comms <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO do
        socket <- initialize
        forever do
            msg <- takeMVar comms
            sendAll socket (prettyPrint msg)
    forkIO (putMVar comms foo)
    putMVar comms bar

I probably wouldn't pick Chan except in unusual circumstances; it has some nontrivial overhead compared to MVar. The place Chan would become meaningful is if for some reason you expect huge bursts of messages to coincidentally need to be sent all at about the same time and senders are likely to have more useful work to do immediately after sending. This seems like an unlikely combo to me... though as always, benchmarking your specific application is the only way to know for sure which is better.
